# why using variable and a number in loop show different outcomes

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

```
a = 1
for number in range(5):
    a = a + number * 5
    print(a)
     #     

for number in range(5):
    a = 1 + number * 5
    print(a)
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you expand on it please?

Comment: In the top loop you constantly change the value of ```a``` by adding to it. In the bottom loop you are only using the number 1. 1 is not equal to numbers larger than 1.

Comment: both  a and 1 have equal value because before i started a loop i put intialised the value of a to 1 .this should show same answer

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, you retain the value of `a`, and add to it `number * 5` in each iteration.
In the second loop, you always take `1` and add to it `number * 5`.

You can, of course, achieve the same behavior with variables, you just need to use another one:

```py
first = 1
for number in range(5):
    a = first + number * 5
    print(a)
```

Comment: Brother ,why does not 1 is add to  number *5 in each each iteration and then retain it to a

Comment: @devashish because you assign the calculation back to `a`